# Use of HLC in some TTR functions

Tags: r, quantmod

I've noticed that the results obtained by some TTR formula which require xts objects containing High-low-close prices (e.g. ADX, ATR and CLV) differ significantly depending on whether HLC is specified in the code. For example:

```
library(quantmod)  # loads TTR
getSymbols("YHOO")
last(ADX(YHOO))
```

gives the following results:

```
2013-09-24 DIp: 48.36026 DIn: 19.65972 DX: 42.19428 ADX: 29.69149
```

whereas

```
last(ADX(HLC(YHOO)))
```

results in:

```
2013-09-24 DIp: 36.85033 DIn: 19.57702 DX: 30.61161 ADX: 23.40803
```

Can anyone explain the reason for the different results and which format (i.e with or without `HLC`) should be used.

Answer (score 4):

A look at the code suggests that it uses the column positions, rather than names:

```
> ADX
function (HLC, n = 14, maType, ...) 
{
    HLC <- try.xts(HLC, error = as.matrix)
    dH <- momentum(HLC[, 1])
    dL <- -momentum(HLC[, 2])
...
```

You should therefore use:

```
ADX(HLC(YHOO))
```

Without `HLC`, you are using open, high and low instead of high, low and close.